# c++ matrix multiplication 2D array faster than 1D

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following codes, they do matrix mult using openmp
lets assume `a=m x n` and `b=n x k`

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        for (l = 0; l < n; l++)
            c[i * k + j] += a[i * n + l] * b[l * k + j];
```

and

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        for (l = 0; l < n; l++)
            c[i][j] += a[i][l] * b[l][j];
```

the latter runs about 1.8x times faster using `g++` with `-O3`. why is that? as far as I know, 2D arrays work just like my 1D code, that's why I'm confused

---

note: the issue persists without openmp as well

Comment: The expression in the the first snippet has 6 more operations than the one in the second snippet.

Comment: Well I knew that, the impact is much bigger than I expected, so I can make the code much faster by creating some pointers that point to first element in every row? xD

Comment: In addition multiplication are always very expensive

Comment: @Mohibeyki your observation is right! As you've just discovered execution time and memory space are closely connected, one could be reduced, but the other will surely grow.

Comment: Apart from @Ron's comment, Have you investigated the effects of [Cache Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Associativity)?  the second snippet may be a victim of Cache-Miss due the Cache Associativity playing in...

Comment: @Jean-Claude Colette on 8080 maybe yes. Multiplications on all modern systems take exactly the same time as additions

Comment: 1D array still can be better for certain matrix sizes. 2D array allocation does not ensure continuous memory area for matrix, which can result in cache-miss

Comment: If you want to have some fun swap the order of the loops over `j` and `k` i.e. make the looper over `j` the inner most loop and the loop over `k` the middle loop. Make sure `m`, `k`, and `l` are sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a [red-herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring), so I'm going to deviate a little to the important point in all this and what is fast and slow in matrix multiplication.

First, you should not be doing matrix multiplication manually. Consider using high-performance libraries such as [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/). OpenBLAS is uses the BLAS interface, which is obnoxious, and you can avoid using it directly with libraries that provide a good and nice C++ interface/wrapper like [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), where you can link to any BLAS library of your choice.

Having said that, let's move to the case where we discuss why matrix multiplication is fast or slow.

Now why the second is faster than the first, I have no idea. This is probably due to some compiler optimization that is not that obvious. One has to analyze the assembly code. However...

The reason why 2D is faster than 1D in general is because you're not doing 1D multiplication right. You're omitting a very important performance optimization, which is vectorization.

The first way should be much faster than the second way. This is because processors can put all multiplications of consecutive elements in memory in 1 instruction (consider reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) for more info). That will be the case when you *ensure that the elements you're multiplying are consecutive in memory*. To do that, just transpose one of the matrices before doing the multiplication.

Also there are other issues that makes 1D multiplication faster, such as [cache-locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) (in multi-threaded programs).

On [scientific computing of SE, this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25283/beating-typical-blas-libraries-matrix-multiplication-performance) discusses beating libraries that are very highly optimized for matrix multiplication. Of course that's highly unlikely, but there you'll find an example that probably gets close to doing that by allowing the compiler to take advantage of vectorization.

Comment: the code is an experiment on openmp, I would never run matrix mult in a production env by myself. I'm experienced on matlab and well aware of BLAS libraries :D

Answer (score 1):

For me, it takes **the same time**.

mat-mult.cpp:

```
#define DIM 1000

#ifdef D2
double a[DIM][DIM], b[DIM][DIM], c[DIM][DIM];
#else
double a[DIM*DIM], b[DIM*DIM], c[DIM*DIM];
#endif

void Test() {
    int i, j, l;
    int k=DIM, m=DIM, n=DIM;
    for (i=0; i<DIM; i++)
    for (j=0; j<DIM; j++) {
#ifdef D2
        a[i][j] = i + j;
        b[i][j] = i - j;
        c[i][j] = 0;
#else
        a[i*DIM+j] = i + j;
        b[i*DIM+j] = i - j;
        c[i*DIM+j] = 0;
#endif
    }

#ifdef D2
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        for (l = 0; l < n; l++)
        c[i][j] += a[i][l] * b[l][j];
#else
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        for (l = 0; l < n; l++)
        c[i * k + j] += a[i * n + l] * b[l * k + j];
#endif
}

main() {
    Test();
}
```

Results:

```
[~/CPP] g++ -O3 -o mat-mult mat-mult.cpp
[~/CPP] ./mat-mult
2.248u 0.064s 0:02.36 97.4% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
[~/CPP] ./mat-mult
2.272u 0.020s 0:02.32 98.7% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
[~/CPP] g++ -DD2 -O3 -o mat-mult mat-mult.cpp
[~/CPP] ./mat-mult
2.244u 0.040s 0:02.33 97.8% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
[~/CPP] ./mat-mult
2.220u 0.032s 0:02.30 97.8% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

You should give **minimal reproducible example**.  The minimal reproducible example is the **full code** which we can copypaste with mouse and run, along with **compilation flags**.  The code should be **minimal**, that is, contain **only what is needed to reproduce your problem**.  If something can be removed from your code, and the problem remains, it is not minimal.

Currently, we have no idea what is the dimensions of your arrays, or even what flags do you use besides -O3 .

**Currently, your question is a classical example of a bad question.**  You throw some incomplete information, hoping we can fill the missing things through telepathy.

Comment: Do you get the same results with DIM = 3 ?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy - yes, no noticeable difference for DIM=3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Ok im getting all kinds of mixed results that are probably related to memory allocation, your code runs 2x slower than my original code but is persistent to its own, my codes are on the repo along with yours at https://github.com/mohibeyki/cuda-tutorial/
I just used -O3 on g++